# Create Unique Index not helping to stop duplicates

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, unique-index

I have a primary Database table named details with three columns of interest -

`_id | Name | BirthDate |  xx   |  xx   |  xx   | ...`

I create a unique index on the above table with the following statement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX _id ON Details (Name, BirthDate)
```

The purpose of the above is to stop duplicate entries in the table, I dont want any name and birthdate to be same. (Although I am not sure if it does that, I tried inserting a new record with same birthdate and name, what I found was thet the previous existing record with same credentials got deleted and this new one inserted at the end) - however this was not the case before I introduced the following:

I have a separate table as follows and called Notifications:

`| _id | NotificationFor | DateToNotify | IsExtraordinary | NotificationData | NotificationDateFor | TypeNotification | RadioType | FriendsName | PrimaryId |`

The above two tables are mapped: `_id` in Details table is the `PrimaryId` in the Notifications Table.

For each _id (record) in the Details table four records are claculated and all of them are inserted into Notifications table.

Now the problem here is that I dont want duplicate records in any of my tables so I put a Unique index on Notifications table as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX _id ON Notifications (NotificationFor, DateToNotify, IsExtraordinary,NotificationData,NotificationDateFor,TypeNotification,RadioType,FriendsName,PrimaryId);
```

I got the following error:

```
10-02 14:16:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(31743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 14:16:31.439: E/AndroidRuntime(31743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx.xxx}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: index _id already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX _id ON Notifications (NotificationFor, DateToNotify, IsExtraordinary,NotificationData,NotificationDateFor,TypeNotification,RadioType,FriendsName,PrimaryId );
```

In my DBAdapter I am executing the code as follows:

```
db.execSQL(uniqueDetails); 
db.execSQL(uniqueNotifications);
```

I changed the uniqueNotifications query to:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NotificationDateFor ON Notifications (NotificationFor, DateToNotify, IsExtraordinary,NotificationData,NotificationDateFor,TypeNotification,RadioType,FriendsName,PrimaryId );
```

Now I dont get the error but I see duplicates in my Notifications Table. ANy hints how I can improve the above and make it work?

To enhance on the above, I read records from a file and insert them into tables I first calculate my data and insert it into details, Inside a for loop in this case I was not using UNIQUE on Notifications - my UNIQUE on details was working fine. But if I encounter a duplicate from Details I want to stop the iteration of the for loop and jump to the next iteration because I dont want the duplicates to be entered in the Notifications table - is there a return type to the UNIQUE Query - if executed on Details I found a duplicate I want to switch my loop to the next iteration - skipping the insert statements regarding the Notifications table. Sorry I know I am bad at explaining stuff.

#### Edit:

I had the following record added to the end of the table, While as before insertion I had this record in original form - now I dont see the older one but this newer one has been inserted at the end:

Details Table - I cannot reproduce both because one has been deleted.

Counterpart in Notifications table: (Record named Tom Hanks at the top)

[image: Record named Tom Hanks at the top]

Record repeated with different _id at the bottom in the same table:

[image]

Below I reproduce the Details table, if you observe the record number 90 does not exist anymore - because it was probably deleted before insertion of the 'same-value' record: (The `_id` and `PrimaryId` values are mapped)

[image]

#### EDIT:

Following is my insert statement( for details table):

```
public void insert(String birthDate, String name, String daysOld, String hoursOld, String uRi, String minutesOld, String months, String seconds, String timestamP, String weeks, String years, String isAdhoc){
        //  InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, "columnTable");

        String INUP= "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Details (BirthDate, Name, isAdhoc, daysOld, hoursOld, imageUri, minutesOld, monthsOld, secondsOld, timestamp, weeksOld, yearsOld) " +
                "values ("+"'"+birthDate+"'"+","+"'"+name+"'"+","+"'"+isAdhoc+"'"+","+"'"+daysOld+"'"+","+"'"+ hoursOld+"'"+","+"'"+ uRi+"'"+","+"'"+minutesOld+"'"+","+"'"+ months+"'"+","+"'"+ seconds+"'"+","+"'"+timestamP+"'"+","+"'"+weeks+"'"+","+"'"+years+"'"+");";  
        mDb.execSQL(INUP);
    }
```

I think the INSERT OR REPLACE in the above might be creating problem.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is a Primary Key/Foreign Key constraint, not an index...or I've misread/misunderstood the question. Indexes are to help speed up data retrieval.

Comment: No I have a primary key - I just dont want duplicates in my tables One record in Details table (With unique name and birth date) - this record has four more records calculated and inserted into Notifications - I dont want duplicates here as well.

Comment: Show the values in the two rows that you think should be rejected as duplicates.

Comment: Sure, I am updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique constraint to enforce unique values.

```
private static final String VERSION_60_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MARKERS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID
        + " INTEGER DEFAULT -1," + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MARKER_SNIPPET + " TEXT," + KEY_MARKER_TITLE + " TEXT,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY(" + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID + ") REFERENCES "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + KEY_ID + ")," + " CONSTRAINT UNQ_"
        + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID + " UNIQUE (" + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID
        + ") ON CONFLICT ABORT)";
```

Best practice:  In code give the constraint a meaning full name.  The above example uses UNQ_ concatenated with the column name for the constraint name.  With a db gui designer use the constraint name from the designer.

Comment: However I am using a UNIQUE COnstraint in my example code. However as I am using INSERT OR REPLACE my older row gets deleted and a new one gets inserted. It would be helpful if I get to know of a way in which the return type tells me if the last insert found a duplicate or not.

Comment: The index didn't create because you already have duplicate rows.  You'll have to run some form of a delete from table where count(key)>1 group by key.  The default is replace if you want an abort you'll have to recreate the table because sqlite doesn't support adding constraints with alter table.  But 1st get rid of your duplicates.

Comment: This project is not in production so I dont have to worry about deleting the duplicates - I start afresh again. I just changed the INSERT OR REPLACE to INSERT and it works. It raises an exception when it encounters a duplicate. FOr now it silently dies but I want to catch this exception and present the user with a Dialogue.